# Fetch inserted text inside 2 previous td using jQuery

Tags: jquery, fetch, html-table

I have multiple rows inside a table like this http://jsfiddle.net/mm6gF/1/ .
I want to show content of 2 previous `td` inside the message. How can I fetch it using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().text();
    var pw = $(this).closest('td').prev().text();
    answer = confirm ('Are you sure to remove this item?\n' + name + ' : ' + pw);
    if (answer)
    {
        alert('Removed');
    }
})​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mm6gF/2/